# How to display a list in python like this?

Tags: python

The list is this:

```
seats = []
seats.append([0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1])
seats.append([0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1])
seats.append([1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0])
seats.append([0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1])
seats.append([0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0])
seats.append([1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1])
```

I want the output so that each row is displayed on a different line, like this:

```
0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1
0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1
1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0
0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1
0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0
1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1
```

I've tried `print(seats)` but it prints all the rows on a single line back-to-back.
I don't have much experience with Python as I'm in 11th grade and I just started learning it.

I don't know what to try next so it would be really amazing if someone cold help me out.

Comment: `for row in seats: print(",".join(str(i) for i in row))`

Answer (score 2):

```
for row in seats:
    print(row)
```

If you don't want the brackets in the output:

```
for row in seats:
    print(", ".join(str(s) for s in row))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for row in seats:
print(str(row).replace("[","").replace("]",""))
```

Desired output

```
0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1
1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0
0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1
0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0
1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1
```